# Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error on Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I got following error while retrieving a data from http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q=Warren,OH&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22 in angular 5 service.

```
message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
```

While entering api URL directly on browser, it will return JSON object list.
Here is the code of my service **weather.service.ts**.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class WeatherService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  dailyForecast() {
    return this._http.get("http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q=Warren,OH&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22")
    .map(result => result);
  }
}
```

Code on **app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { WeatherService } from './weather.service';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [WeatherService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and code on **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { WeatherService } from './weather.service';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private _weather: WeatherService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._weather.dailyForecast()
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
}
```

I cannot figure out what is going wrong on it.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug on `HttpClient` , you cannot fix otherwise use : 
prefix stripping by using `JSON.parse` always.

Comment: Hello, I'm with the same problem. Can you explain better how I can resolve?

Answer (score -1):

It's CORS issue, please add `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` in your backend code.

Comment: I'm not using CORS, I'm using proxy. Still I get this error.